# caching rtmp streams

Tags: caching, rtmp, squid

Is there any way to cache rtmp streams?
Normally squid successfully caches http based videos. What about rtmp? 
Do you know any other tool?

about rtmp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol

Thank you,